# Pure js stream from webcamera to server

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, rtmp

Is it possible to capture stream from webcamera(in front end) and stream it to server via **hls** or **rtmp** with pure js(no flash).
And if there are another protocol which let send stream as stream(unlike hls), will be prefered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found solution.
There is no (yet) any way to "convert" stream received from `navigator.getUserMedia()` to `rtmp` in front-end.
But we can use MediaRecorder Api. 
**In client Side**

```
const stream = await navigator.getUserMedia(options)
const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream)
recorder.ondataavailable = (e) => { socket.emit('binaryData',e.data) }
recorder(start)
```

**In backend**

```
const ffmpegProcess = spawn('ffmpeg', ffmpegCommans)
socket.on('binaryData', (data) => { 
  ffmpegProcess.stdin.write(params.data)
})
```

FFmpeg will convert vp8 video stream to hls/rtmp/rtsp or whatever.

In this way we can get video stream with latency 3(average) second  .

Comment: Can you post a link to a Github repo that implements this?

Comment: unfortunatly no, project is private, but check this repo.
almost there .
https://github.com/chenxiaoqino/getusermedia-to-rtmp

Comment: Thanks @Kandrat I'll check that out