# Audio out of sync while playling stream of webm chunks

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, webm, media-source

I have webm chunks ( recorded from webcam and send via websocket ).

In client side i have

```
this.sourceBuffer = this.mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vp8,opus"');
this.sourceBuffer.mode = 'sequence'
....
socket.on('streamPart', (chunk)=>{
   this.sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(data);
})
```

Video is playing, **but** after few chunks video is "late". I heared sound and after few seconds i see part where sound must be.

In [chrome://media-internals](http://chrome://media-internals/) are many logs like

debug `Audio buffer splice at PTS=12601000us. Trimmed tail of overlapped buffer (PTS=12583000us) by 2000us.`

and

warning `Large timestamp gap detected; may cause AV sync to drift. time:12543000us expected:12332500us delta:210500us`

This problem exists on

**Chrome Version: 79.0.3945.88**, 
**Opera Version: 65.0.3467.78**

And everything is ok on **Firefox: 71.0**

**Important thing** Web chunks are not corrupted. I download them manually and play- they are ok.

How can i fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: did you got any solution ?

Comment: unfortunately no, i turn to using ffmpeg hls converting instead of transferring "pure" mediastream

Comment: can you please explain more,how did you used ffmeg for your solution

Comment: check this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61026232/1746797